# Android ChipGroup: Add child view only in XML to check layout design

Tags: android, android-chips, android-designer

I have been trying this scenario. I have a `ChipGroup` and I only add the `Chips` dynamically into the group. Now if I want to check the layout design I do it by adding some `Chips` temporarily in the xml. Then, when the app builds, these temporary `Chips` needs to be removed. I often forget to remove these and wonder why the `ChipGroup` is having additional `Chips`. Then it strikes to me that I haven't removed those `Chips` in the xml.

If its as a `ListView`, we have the `tools:listItem` attribute to check its child views, but is there anything similar to check with other `LayoutGroups`?

PS: I am not having any issues implementing the `Chips` or the `ChipGroup`. I just need a suggestion to follow a better practice to avoid mistakes.